# Connot connect to .dbf file in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, database, dbf

I'm trying to connect access *.dbf file in ASP.NET select some data and display in html. However I cannot make connection. I suppose, the problem lays in the connection string.

```
OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\Data;Extended Properties=dBASE 5.0;User ID=Admin;Password=;";

conn.Open();
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not
>   found and no default driver specified

Unfortunately, none none of the solutions posted in older questions solved my problem.

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015, Windows 10 64-bit.

I guess, that the Provider may be wrong. However I'm not so good in this topic, so I don't know how to do this in a proper way. I'd be very thankful for some step-by-step instruction and for any useful advice.

the *.dbf file is one of the files from the archive here:
[DBF File](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=5f4f92a040d54aaaa5f4f94f9c1d0d17)

Comment: See [this site](https://www.connectionstrings.com/dbf-foxpro/) and try different connection strings (providers).

Comment: Your connection string is just this - `Data Source=c:\Data` - don't you need to provide the name of the file?

Answer (score 1):

Jet 4.0 works in 32 bit mode only. You'll need to update your application to run in 32 bit mode. Check this information from connectionstrings.com about [running jet in 32 bit mode on a 64 bit machine](https://www.connectionstrings.com/using-jet-in-64-bit-environments/).

You can see this reference from connectionstrings.com that shows the [microsoft dbf connection](https://www.connectionstrings.com/dbf-foxpro/). It appears to use roman numerials instead of 5.0 as you are using for the dbase version.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to connect with this code, but needed to instal VFPOLEDB driver.

```
private DataTable myTable()
{
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=c:\\Data\\;Extended Properties=dBASE IV;User ID=;Password=;");
        conn.Open();

        string query = "SELECT * FROM d:\\data\\Earthquakes1970";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

        conn.Close();

        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: Your connection should point to the PATH that the data tables (.dbf) files are located.  THEN your query can just refer to the table name without a fully qualified path reference.  Easier to deal with, especially if a path ever changes, you just change the connection string for the path.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this. I am running these code with windows 10. and visual studio 2010.

Put your database files in App_Data folder. and use following connection string.
it is working for me.

**web.config file**

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="conn" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|;Extended Properties=dBASE IV;User ID=Admin;Password=;" />
</connectionStrings>
```